# why local storage is being cleared after browser closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

```
//set item:
$window.localStorage.setItem("xyz", '123')


//get item:
$window.localStorage.getItem("xyz");
```

Everythings works fine, we can see the "xyz" variable in chrome devtool->localstorage and also able to get the "xyz" value, but after browser closed and reopens the localstorage is showing blank.

Is there something i am missing?
can someone please help me out from this?

Comment: Check your Chrome settings to see if you have "Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome" set.

Comment: It's in Privacy and Security settings.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, it works